# Elastalert not alerting via email?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastalert

I am trying to utilize a simple rule using Elastalert, and it seems to not be functioning properly. My rule is:

```
name: termrule
 type: Any
 index: logstash-*
fields:
- "ip"
filter:
- term:
 _type: "log"
- term:
   agentip: 1.2.3.4
  alert:
 email:
- "myemail@company.com "

 ##remote mailserver
smtp_host:
- "remote mailserver_ip"
```

My config.yaml

```
es_host: 1.2.3.4
es_port: 9200
rules_folder: rules
run_every:
minutes: 1
buffer_time:
 minutes: 15
writeback_index: elastalert_status
alert_time_limit:
days: 2
es_conn_timeout: 20
```

debug log :

```
INFO:elastalert:Note: In debug mode, alerts will be logged to console but NOT actually sent. To send them, use --verbose.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
 File "/home/george/elastalert/elastalert/elastalert.py", line 1408, in       <module>
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
File "/home/george/elastalert/elastalert/elastalert.py", line 1403, in main
client = ElastAlerter(args)
File "/home/george/elastalert/elastalert/elastalert.py", line 94, in __init__
self.conf = load_rules(self.args)
File "elastalert/config.py", line 400, in load_rules
raise EAException('Error loading file %s: %s' % (rule_file, e))
elastalert.util.EAException: Error loading file ./rules/term_rule.yaml:  Invalid Rule: termrule
{'index': 'logstash-*', 'name': 'termrule', 'fields': ['agentip'], 'smtp_host': ['X.X.X.X'], 'alert': ['email'], 'filter': [{'term': {'_type': 'log'}}, {'term': {'agentip': '1.2.3.4'}}], 'rule_file': './rules/term_rule.yaml', 'type': 'Any', 'email': ['myemail@company.com']} is not valid under any of the given schemas
```

But when I run with the command

```
 #sudo python -m elastalert.elastalert --config ./config.yaml --rule ./rules/term_rule.yaml --es_debug_trace ./elastalert.log
```

I just ran the Kibana query to verify that my filters which returned 5 hits but my elastalert.log is empty 
and I didn’t get any alert email,
If the rule is 'any' then any query hits should be alerted on, but as you can see it is not. Any ideas?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have some elastalert useful logs you can share?

Comment: @Val, 
I try to use --es_debug alert.log, but the alert.log still empty .

Comment: You should use `--debug`

Comment: @Val, $ sudo python -m elastalert.elastalert --config ./config.yaml --rule ./rules/term_rule.yaml --start NOW --debug ./alert.log                   usage: elastalert.py [-h] [--config CONFIG] [--debug] [--rule RULE]
                     [--silence SILENCE] [--start START] [--end END]
                     [--verbose] [--pin_rules] [--es_debug]
                     [--es_debug_trace ES_DEBUG_TRACE]
elastalert.py: error: unrecognized arguments: ./alert.log

Comment: Just `--debug` not need for `./alert.log`

Comment: @val, i have add some debug log

Comment: You should probably fix your rule file first: `Invalid Rule: termrule`

Comment: But I'm really don't know what's wrong with my rule .

Comment: As far as I can see, your YAML rule file is not properly indented

Comment: @Val, the rule is from elastalert example. please advise how to modify it ?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, your rule type has to be all lower case, ie. 'any' instead of 'Any'

Answer (score 0):

YAML is white space sensitive. I'm not sure if the copy and paste went wrong but some of the fields look misaligned:

```
  alert:
 email:
- "myemail@company.com
```

I would change to

```
alert:
- "email"
email:
- "myemail@company.com"
```

Also you have

```
smtp_host:
- "remote mailserver_ip"
```

Which is being converted into an array in your output error message. I don't think you can have a list of SMTP relays, so it might not be matching a schema that can deal with it. Try changing it to

```
smtp_host: "remote mailserver_ip"
```